# Trying to model the relationship between two people in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, join

I have the following two simple classes:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :parent_child_assignments

  has_many :children, :through => :parent_child_assignments
  has_many :parents, :through => :parent_child_assignments
end

class ParentChildAssignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => "Person"
  belongs_to :child, :class_name => "Person"
end
```

created from the following rails commands

```
rails generate model Person name:string
rails generate model ParentChildAssignment parent_id:integer child_id:integer
```

I can get one direction (joe.children or joe.parents) to work but not both

Someone must have asked this question before, but I can't find it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you need to specify the foreign key in the has many part. For instance: `has_many :children, :through => :parent_child_assignments, class_name: 'Person', foreign_key: :child_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The classes should look like:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :parent_child_assignments_as_parent, class_name: 'ParentChildAssignment', :foreign_key => :parent_id
  has_many :parent_child_assignments_as_child,  class_name: 'ParentChildAssignment', :foreign_key => :child_id

  has_many :children, :through => :parent_child_assignments_as_parent
  has_many :parents,  :through => :parent_child_assignments_as_child
end

class ParentChildAssignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => "Person", :foreign_key => :parent_id
  belongs_to :child, :class_name => "Person", :foreign_key => :child_id
end
```

Comment: The answer was actually given to me offline by a friend.